# How to prevent Android gradle build from running device tests as unit-tests

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am upgrading my Android project [loopback-sdk-android](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android) from Android Gradle Build Tools 0.9 to 1.1. The migration went fine as far as the IDE is concerned, I can compile the project and run device tests on an emulator.

However, the command-line build is broken. When I run `./gradlew build` (or `./gradlew test`), build tools incorrectly pick up files from `src/androidTest/java` as unit-test files and the build fails with a bunch of NoClassDefFoundError.

```
com.strongloop.android.loopback.test.AsyncTestCase > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

`./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` works correctly and runs the tests from `src/androidTest/java` on an emulator.

**How can I configure the gradle build so that it does not run device tests as pure unit-tests?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: remove old build artefacts after upgrading the build file.

```
./gradlew clean
```

For posterity, here is a short snippet that confirmed to me that the build is correctly picking up the source files:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        logger.info("androidTest java srcdirs");
        androidTest.java.srcDirs.each { d -> logger.info("\t" + d) }

        logger.info("test java srcdirs");
        test.java.srcDirs.each { d -> logger.info("\t" + d) }
    }
}
```

`./gradlew --info test` produced the following result:

```
androidTest java srcdirs
    ~/src/loopback/android/src/androidTest/java
test java srcdirs
    ~/src/loopback/android/src/test/java
```

Answer (score 0):

open your file build.gradle(Module:app)

comment your test compilation in android{}

//testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"